# Firebase PHP update specific Array index in Field

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't how how or if its is possible to udpate an Array value with a custom index.
My code is in PHP but i can swith to JS if it is nessesary

Here my challange:
I have an itemarry (with many rows and different kinds) which includes a futher array.
and i want to change a custom row of the itmes array

for e.g. I want to change the status and the userid of the arrayindex "Items[0]"

I'D tried it with

```
$document = $db->collection('events')->document($eventid);    
$document->update([
        [
            'path' => 'items.0', 'value' => FieldValue::arrayUnion([[
            'status' => '1',
            'userid' => '383747493834',
            ]])
        ]
    ]);
```

and

```
$document->set([
        'regions' => FieldValue::arrayUnion([[
            'kind' => 'test',
            'status' => '1',
            'userid' => '383747493834',
        ]])
    ], ['merge' => true]);
```

but nothing work in the first example Firebase add a new Field in the document and in the second example a new row was added

[image: Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in Firestore to update a value at a specific index in an array with just a write operation.

If your use-case requires this sort of update, you'll need to:

1. Read the document from Firestore
2. Get the *entire* array from the document
3. Update the data in that array
4. Write the entire array back to Firestore

Comment: Thanks, that was my fear. I switched over to references :)